# Why does the dicyclic group have exactly one involution?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, involutions

This is **Exercise 12.2(a)** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Dicyclic+involution), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

Roman defines, on page 350 *ibid.*, the dicyclic group of order $4n, n>1$, using the presentation

$${\rm Dic}_n\cong \langle x,y\mid x^{2n}, y^2=x^n, yx=x^{2n-1}y=x^{-1}y\rangle.\tag{$\mathcal{P}$}$$

### The Question:

> Why does the dicyclic group have exactly one involution?

### Thoughts:

Since the order of the dicyclic group is $4n$, two divides its order, so by Cauchy's Theorem, an involution exists; but this is nuking the problem, since $y^2=x^n$ is an involution by the relation $x^{2n}=1$ in $(\mathcal{P})$.

Suppose, then, for a contradiction, that $z^2=1$ for some $z\in{\rm Dic}_n$ with $z\neq x^n$. Now what do I do?

Experience tells me that we can write each element of ${\rm Dic}_n$ in the form $x^ay^b$ for some $a\in\overline{0,2n-1},$ $b\in\{0,1\}$. This follows from the orders of $x$ and of $y$, together with the last relation in $(\mathcal{P})$. I'm fairly sure this will help.

---

*An Example:*

Let $n=2$. Then ${\rm Dic}_2$ is isomorphic to the quaternion group. Clearly $-1$ is its only involution.

---

*My Background:*

I work with presentations a lot, so this seems like a problem I should be able to solve myself with a bit of a hint. I don't have much experience with dicyclic groups.

---

*Further Context:*

This question is from a rather introductory chapter titled **"Free Groups and Presentations"**, so the tools available aren't as sophisticated as in, say, Magnus *et al.*'s *"Combinatorial Group Theory: [. . .]"*.

Please help :)

Comment: Not sure why you would take $b$ to be $0$ or $3$; why not $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Good question, @ArturoMagidin. I guessed that $y$ has order $4$. That's it, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is clear that one involution is $x^n$, and this is the only power of $x$ that is an involution. Every other element can be written in the form $x^iy$ with $0\leq i\lt 2n$, using the given relations. Note that any even power of $y$ can be written as a power of $x$, since $(y^{2k}) = (y^2)^k = (x^n)^k = x^{kn}$, and any odd power of $y$ can be written as a power of $x$ times $y$, since $y^{2k+1} = y^{2k}y = x^{kn}y$.  That’s why every element can be written as $x^iy^j$ with $0\leq i\lt 2n$, $0\leq j\lt 2$. Uniqueness takes a bit more work, but isn’t terribly hard.

We have
$$(x^iy)^2 = x^iyx^iy = x^ix^{-i}y^2 = x^n.$$
So this is trivial if and only if $x^n=e$, which cannot happen since $x$ has order $2n$. Thus, none of these elements are involutions, and so the only involution is $x^n$, which we already found.

Comment: *NB:* Isn't $$(y^2)^k\neq (x^2)^k$$ unless $n=2$?

Comment: @Shaun: I was working off your (typo-ed) presentation. It was fixed while you were writing your comment. (At least, I thought I had, but apparently I hadn’t... weird)